# MySQL Making pair of values from one column based on similarity on other column

Tags: mysql, sql

I'll apologize in advance because this has likely been answered somewhere but I could not seem to be able to find the answer I need, and can't manage to adapt other code I have found to my needs.

I have a table as follows:

```
   NAME          PAPER
    A             10
    B             20
    C             10
    D             30
    A             40
    C             20
    E             30
    F             40
    G             10
```

And I want to produce a pair of value in the name, if they have the same paper. And both of the columns can have duplicate number .

For example, the result of the above would be:

```
   NAME          NAME
    A             C
    B             C
    D             E
    A             F
    A             G
    B             G
```

Is there any function in mysql that can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select a.name, b.name
from myTable a 
inner join myTtable b
on a.paper=b.paper and a.name<b.name
```

[SQL FIDDLE TEST](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ce51f0/2)

Results

```
A   C
B   C
D   E
A   F
A   G
C   G
```